# why does my Verilog adder-subtractor fail the addition here with 1 more than correct answer?

Tags: binary, verilog, modelsim, quartus

I wrote a 4-bit full-adder-subtractor, and my code managed to operate subtraction but failed operating addition with 1 more than the correct answer: 0101+0101=1011. Help!

Here's the full-adder-subtractor code:

```
module Add_sub(x,y,co,u,en);
  input [3:0] x, y;
  input en; // en=1: add;   en=0:sub
  output [3:0] u;
  output co;


  wire [3:1]carry;
  FA M0(x[0],   y[0],   en,     en, u[0],   carry[1]);
  FA M1(x[1],   y[1],   carry[1],   en, u[1],   carry[2]);
  FA M2(x[2],   y[2],   carry[2],   en, u[2],   carry[3]);
  FA M3(x[3],   y[3],   carry[3],   en, u[3],   co);

endmodule

module FA(x,y,cin,en,u,co);
  input x, y, cin, en;
  output u, co;

  wire b = !x^en;
  assign u = x^y^cin;
  assign co = (b&y)|(b&cin)|(y&cin);

endmodule
```

Here's the testbench code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module testbench();
  reg [3:0]x, y;
  reg en;
  wire[3:0]u;
  wire co;
  
  Add_sub tb(.x(x), .y(y), .co(co), .u(u), .en (en));

  initial begin
    $monitor ($time, "x=%b, y=%b, co=%b, u=%b, en=%b",x,y,co,u,en);
  end

  initial begin
    #0  x=5;    y=5;    en=1;   // add operation
    #20 x=5;    y=5;    en=0;   // sub operation
    #20 x=8;    y=1;    en=1;   // add operation
    #20 x=8;    y=1;    en=0;   // sub operation
    #20 $stop;
  end
endmodule
```

Here's the simulation Wave:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I re-wrote your code as following:

```
module Add_sub(x,y,co,u,en);
  input [3:0] x, y;
  input en; // en=1: add;   en=0:sub
  output [3:0] u;
  output co;
  wire [3:1]carry;
  wire ci = ~en;
  FA M0(x[0], y[0], ci,       en, u[0], carry[1]);
  FA M1(x[1], y[1], carry[1], en, u[1], carry[2]);
  FA M2(x[2], y[2], carry[2], en, u[2], carry[3]);
  FA M3(x[3], y[3], carry[3], en, u[3], co);
endmodule

module FA(x,y,cin,en,u,co);
  input x, y, cin, en;
  output u, co;
  wire b = en ? y : (~y);
  assign u = x^b^cin;
  assign co = (b&x)|(b&cin)|(x&cin);
endmodule
```